# Choose production bug happening on turn 0

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

This bug is completely irritating, because on turn 0 when I play as Rome, I can move my units around perfectly fine, but when I try to choose production it just hovers over my city, and does nothing, I tried reloading it, to no avail. I tried what the people at 2k recommended and it didn't work. How can I fix this?